# What's the difference between debugging and running the debug variant?

Tags: android-studio

In Android Studio, you can "Run" or "Debug" your application using these buttons:

[image: Run and Debug in Android Studio]

Also, you can choose a debug or release build variant in the Build Variants window:

[image: Build Variants window]

What's the difference between pressing the Debug button and choosing the debug variant, or pressing the Run button and choosing the release variant? Would it make any difference if I debug the debug or the release version?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The build variant generally describes how the application gets built - for example the debug variant builds a debug-able application whereas the release variant is optimized, signed and does not support debugging.

- `Run` simply launches the application (regardless of what the flavor is).
- `Debug` essentially does the same thing but will **stop at any breakpoints** that you might have set ...